# Accidentally deleted file from /Library/Preferences/

Tags: command-line, preferences, extended-attributes

I have deleted the file
`com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`  from `/Library/Preferences/` by mistake.
I have a copy of the file saved.
I hoped the file would be reconstructed after reboot, but that didn't happen. A file with the same name in `~/Library/Preferences/` was reconstructed, but not the one in `/Library/Preferences/`.

Can I somehow make reconstruct this file?

I copied the saved copy to `/Library/Preferences/` but it has different file permissions. In particular I had to change the owner to root, and there were some additional extended attributes. I tried to remove the extended attribute `com.apple.provenance` but the command `xattr -d ...` simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why did you want to delete this file? Was it taking a lot of space?

Comment: I was installing custom keyboard layouts and wanted to edit the file, and I couldn't, even with sudo, so I overwrote it with a copy of the edited file.

Comment: My `com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` (unchanged since 1st created 20191217) does not have any xattrs. From a web search: the com.apple.provenance is new and nobody know what it is!

Answer (score 1):

You could always reinstall the Mac operating system if you don't have a Time Machine backup. Reinstallation won't remove data from your Mac.

1. Restart the Mac and press and hold Command (⌘)-R until you see an Apple logo.
2. Select Reinstall MacOS from the menu. If you have a Time Machine backup you could choose that here instead.

Comment: I followed your instructions to reinstall the OS, however I had not deleted the file prior to the reinstall. The file in question was not reconstructed, which I noticed because the attributes of the file did not change (and they should have changed).

Comment: @Kolja Most likely because it is not included directly in the macOS install. I see that my  `com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` 17-Dec-2019 (when I last did a clean install) and not been modified since even though I am not using macOS 13.