# What is the `com.apple.provenance` extended attribute on macOS 13 (Ventura)

Tags: macos, ventura

Now all new created files/folders have this attribute `com.apple.provenance` set to a empty string or something. Is this the default behavior or I did something wrong to my laptop? (This is the formatted output by a terminal program called `exa`, and those `@` signs appended there indicate that some extended attributes has been set):

```
drwx------     - Foo 17 Jan 18:21   Desktop
drwx------     - Foo 17 Jan 18:21   .Trash
drwxr-xr-x@    - Foo 17 Jan 18:21   test1
.rw-r--r--@    0 Foo 17 Jan 18:25   test
```

Running command `ls -l@a test` gave me this:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Foo  staff  0 Jan 17 19:56 test
        com.apple.provenance    11
```