# Undeleteable (dataless?) folder in MacOS: Permission denied, compressed chflag

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystem, folders, apfs

I'm having a problem deleting a folder that was previously managed by Microsoft OneDrive.

The folder is called "WP". I already tried: sudo, disabling SIP, removing chflags.

```
❯ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
❯ ls -la WP
total 0
drwxrwxrwx@ 7 user staff 224B Mar 20 11:26 ./
drwxrwxrwx@ 4 user staff 128B Mar 25 17:03 ../
❯ rm -r WP
rm: WP: Permission denied
❯ sudo rm -r WP
Password:
rm: WP: Permission denied
❯ sudo rmdir WP
rmdir: WP: Directory not empty
```

I also checked the xattrs, but there is only this:

```
❯ xattr -l WP
com.apple.provenance:
```

It got interesting, when I listed the chflags:

```
❯ ls -lO .
total 0
drwxrwxrwx@ 7 user staff compressed 224B Mar 20 11:26 WP/
```

But removing the compressed flag is not allowed:

```
❯ sudo chflags -R 0 WP
chflags: WP: Operation not permitted
```

The folder can be moved (but not across Volumes, the error message then indicates that it needs to be loaded first: "The operation can’t be completed because “WP” needs to be downloaded."). It was originally in OneDrive before being moved to the Trash, now I have moved it to `/tmp`.

I assume it has something to do with the folder being dataless/compressed from being created in OneDrive. Any idea how I can delete this folder?

Comment: Have you tried this: sudo rm -fr WP

Comment: Where is `WP`? In your home folder, in Library? Have you checked xattr, `ls -l@`? The `@` would indicate there are extended attrs.

Comment: @LincD. Yes, the -f flag makes no difference.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I added the information above. Originally the folder was in OneDrive, then moved to the Trash, and now residing in `/tmp` for the lack of a better location.

Comment: OK, if it's in /tmp, it should be deleted automatically when you reboot. Does that happen? If not, what happens if you move it to the Trash and empty after rebooting?

Comment: `ls -lae` to show ACLs.  There may be everyone deny delete.

Comment: Is OneDrive running? Can you delete the folder after completely stopping OneDrive?

Comment: @Gilby There are no ACLs, which would be indicated with a + sign on the ls. I also made sure to remove any with `chmod -R -N`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the \`com.apple.provenance\` xattr (extended attribute) and how can I delete it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450118/what-is-the-com-apple-provenance-xattr-extended-attribute-and-how-can-i-dele)

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni No, doesn't work.

Comment: By any chance, are you using MS365 or OneDrive?

Comment: @Allan Did you read the first sentence of my question until the very end?

Comment: My bad.  That is the camera roll directory.  Try turning off photo upload.

Comment: @Allan It isn't. It's a (random) folder that was previously synced by OneDrive. Please read the question in full before answering with random comments.

Comment: “Random” folder.  Sure.  Ok

Answer (score 0):

[Researching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=macos+what+does+com.apple.provenance+in+extended+attribute+mean&t=ffab&ia=web) this a bit turned up a variety of responses that seem to be in conflict with each other - in some cases even being dependent on one's choice of terminal application!

Here's an answer that [***may help***](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/723397); it's recent, and from one of Apple's "Developer Forums":

1. Restart your mac in [Safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac)
2. Once in Safe mode, start the Terminal app from Utilities
3. Enter the following command to disable SIP:

```
csrutil disable --with basesystem --with dtrace --with kext
```

4. Restart your mac in UN-Safe mode `:P`
5. Once started, try the following command:

```shell
xattr -d com.apple.provenance WP
```

This may or may not work; if it does, you should be able to delete the pest after removing the `xattr`. Obviously I can't try it on my own system because AFAIK, I don't have such a file. Also, the solutions (such as they are) are likely OS-dependent (OP didn't mention OS version) - and Apple's designs and usage may be evolving??

According to [H. Oakley](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/03/13/ventura-has-changed-app-quarantine-with-a-new-xattr/), this little bit of "genius" first appeared in macOS Ventura. His article is interesting, and there are at least two follow-up articles: [1](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/05/10/how-macos-now-tracks-the-provenance-of-apps/), [2](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/05/18/inspect-and-control-extended-attributes-with-xattred-1-4/).

And I suppose I shouldn't leave here without addressing the question that always arises when reading of such "discoveries" in Apple's proprietary software: ***Is this a "good thing" - or a "bad thing"?*** If it's being used to protect users from *the bad guys*, that's clearly a *"good thing"*, but I have doubts that: 1) Apple's secrecy has a positive effect overall, and 2) their motives are as pure as the new-driven snow. In this case (for this question) we see that Microsoft *may be* using it; but of course this may or may not be Microsoft's doing. All I'm trying to say really is that I do not favor Apple's secretive approach to the software business - esp. when it concerns my safety.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer, unfortunately the xattr is not the culprit here at all. I am already in contact with Hal, and he suspects the same cause (dataless, compressed).

Comment: @tholu: OK, but I presume `xattred` did identify it with `com.apple.provenance`? In any case, I wish you the best of luck. I'll leave this answer here for a while in case it helps someone else.  It seems this exercise is not dissimilar to chasing a computer virus :-/

Comment: Yes it does, see the second paragraph.

Comment: Just want to point out: his name is "Howard" Oakley—not "Hal".

Comment: @luckman212: FYI... ever heard of something called a [nickname](https://nicknamedb.com/Howard)?